# i want to make effect of press button in android

Tags: android

i want to make effect of press button in android when i press button than i want to make effect on thin ans when i puts offf this button than it will make as it is like...before.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use selector for button image:

```
 < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 < selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     < item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/on_button_image"/> 
     < item android:drawable="@drawable/off_button_image"/> 
< /selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the original image with the  new image(image with press effect) within the onclick method .
See the following code:

```
Imagebutton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Imagebutton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image);

                //do what you want to do

            }
        });
```